# Ajax call, make array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, maps

I would like to make a object with the data I retrieve with ajax call.
The problem, I call my function every ajax call and it make a array with 1 entries * my 10 files but I would like 1 array with 10 entries.

```
function mapXML(data) {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let maps = 'maps/' + data[i];
    $.ajax({
      url: maps,
      type: "GET",
      datatype: "xml",
      success: function(xml) {
        traitementCarte(xml)

      }
    });
  }
}

function traitementCarte(xml) {

  console.log(xml)

  let lat = [],
    lng = [],
    test = [];

  var lastElementLat,
    lastElementLng;

  $(xml).find('trkpt').each(function(i, el) {
    lat[i] = parseFloat($(this).attr('lat'));
    lng[i] = parseFloat($(this).attr('lon'))
  });

  lastElementLat = lat[lat.length - 1];
  lastElementLng = lng[lng.length - 1];

  let locations = {
    lat: lastElementLat,
    lon: lastElementLng
  };

  test.push(locations);

  console.log(test)
}
```

[image: Console.log(test)]

I don't have solution for my problem.
Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the returned xml data from the ajax call? Along with the other code that is calling your ajax function, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the array variable outside the `traitementCarte()` function, otherwise you're creating a new array every time you call it.

```
var test = [];

function traitementCarte(xml) {

  console.log(xml)

  let lat = [],
    lng = [];

  var lastElementLat,
    lastElementLng;

  $(xml).find('trkpt').each(function(i, el) {
    lat[i] = parseFloat($(this).attr('lat'));
    lng[i] = parseFloat($(this).attr('lon'))
  });

  lastElementLat = lat[lat.length - 1];
  lastElementLng = lng[lng.length - 1];

  let locations = {
    lat: lastElementLat,
    lon: lastElementLng
  };

  test.push(locations);

  console.log(test)
}
```

Comment: Such a simple fix, wish I could give it two upvotes!

Comment: OMG, I don't test that... beginner error .. thank you very much